# Vue router: this.$route.fullPath does not reflect what it's in address bar?

Tags: vue.js, vue-router

I'm trying to get a handle on how Vue Router works and I'm not sure why if I `console.log(this.$route.fullPath)` in `updated() {}` the result does not match what's in my browser address bar.

I do understand that window.location.href might be what I want, but I want to know why $route.fullPath isn't the current window location (beginning with the URI components that is at least)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because the Vue router only concerns itself with the fragment part of the URL, i.e. the part after the # sign.